# Generalizing the natural numbers - has this been studied before?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

The ordinals numbers generalize the natural numbers and satisfy a generalized induction principle. However, the algebraic properties of the ordinal numbers aren't so good. For example, ordinal sums are neither commutative, nor left-cancellative.

It was pointed out in the comments that these deficiencies can be remedied by working with the [Hessenberg sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations) of ordinals. However, this introduces a new problem, which is that despite the fact that $1 \leq \omega$, nonetheless the equation $1 \boxplus x = \omega$ has no ordinal-valued solution (intuitively, it would have be $x = \omega - 1$). Here I am using $\boxplus$ to denote the Hessenberg sum.

So, I was trying to generalize the natural numbers in a different way, sacrificing proof by induction but preserving all those nice algebraic properties. I came up with the following idea, but haven't seen it anywhere.

**Has the following idea been studied?**

In what follows, lets take $\mathbb{N}$ to start at $1$. So

$$\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\cdots\}.$$

Also, let $\mathbb{M}$ denote the positive rational numbers, with the convention $0 \notin \mathbb{M}.$

Then $\mathbb{N}$ embeds naturally into $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{M},$ each of which embed naturally into $\mathbb{Q}$. We will try to recreate this system of embeddings.

*Note that what follows is highly speculative, and there may be severe mistakes.*

---

Let $\mathbb{N}'$ denote the set of all (non-zero) univariate integer polynomials with positive leading coefficient, ordered lexicographically. Then $\mathbb{N}'$ is closed under addition and multiplication, and these operations are commutative and associative on $\mathbb{N}'.$ We also have distributivity of multiplication over addition.

Furthermore, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}',$ I believe the following hold.

1. If $a < b,$ then for all $x \in \mathbb{N}'$ we have $x+a < x+b$ and $xa < xb.$
2. The following are equivalent. In particular, i implies ii and ii implies iii.

   i. There exists $x$ satisfying $x+a=b$.

   ii. $a < b$

   iii. There exists unique $x$ satisfying $x+a=b$.
3. For all $x \in \mathbb{N}'$ we have the following. If $x+a=x+b$, then $a=b.$ If $xa=xb$, then $a=b.$

---

Now let $\mathbb{Z}'$ denote the set of *all* univariate integer polynomials, ordered lexicographically. Thus $\mathbb{N}' = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}' \mid x > 0\}.$ Also, $\mathbb{Z}'$ is an integral domain.

Furthermore, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}',$ I believe the following hold.

1. If $a < b,$ then for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}'$ we have $x+a < x+b.$
2. If $a < b,$ then for all $x \in \mathbb{N}'$ we have $xa < xb.$
3. There exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}'$ satisfying $x+a = 0.$
4. For all **non-zero** $x \in \mathbb{Z}'$ such that $xa=xb$, we have $a=b.$

---

Now recall that $\mathbb{M}$ is our notation for the positive rational numbers. By analogy, let $\mathbb{M}'$ denote the set of all equivalence classes of ordered pairs $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}'$ with equivalence defined such that $$(a,b) \sim (a',b') \;\Leftrightarrow \; ab' = a'b.$$

Most likely, the set $\mathbb{M}'$ can be equipped with addition, multiplication in the usual way. Furthermore, define $$[(a,b)] < [(a',b')] \Leftrightarrow ab' < a'b.$$

I'm guessing that this is well-defined, and that the order relation interacts nicely with addition and multiplication.

---

Finally, we can construct an ordered field $\mathbb{Q}'$ in at least two different ways.

One way is to replace $\mathbb{N}'$ with $\mathbb{Z}'$ above. The order relation also needs to be defined in a more complicated way; presumably, the following definition will do the trick. $$[(a,b)] < [(a',b')] \Leftrightarrow (bb' > 0 \wedge ab' < a'b) \vee (bb' < 0 \wedge a'b < ab').$$

This is basically just the definition I got off Wikipedia's section on the [formal construction of the rational numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Formal_construction).

Another, most likely simpler approach would be to define $\mathbb{Q}'$ by gluing together two copies of $\mathbb{M}'$ with an element $0$ wedged between them. Presumably, both approaches to constructing $\mathbb{Q}'$ give us the same result, and this would be our first major theorem.

Finally, I'm guessing that we get the usual system of embeddings. So $\mathbb{N}'$ embeds naturally into $\mathbb{Z}'$ and $\mathbb{M}',$ and both these structures embed naturally into $\mathbb{Q}'.$ Indeed, its probably safe to view these embeddings as inclusions.

Comment: As for "For example, ordinal sums are neither commutative, nor left-cancellative.", look at the Hessenberg sum.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, yes thats a good point. But I think the natural sum also has issues. Like I dont think its right-surjective. E.g. the equation $1+x=\omega$ has no solution. I think

Comment: As you seem aware, every integral domain has its field of fractions. The lexicographic order on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ does extend to an ordering of the field (in the sense that what we get is an ordered field) if we insist to extend it in the manner you described where *only* representatives with positive denominators are chosen.

Comment: Oh, $1+\omega=\omega$, but as $\omega$ has no maximal element $x+1=\omega$ has no solution.

Comment: @JonathanY., sorry my last comment was unclear. I wish I could still edit it. I was referring specifically to the [Hessenberg sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations), as Martin calls it.

Comment: No, the mistake is mine. You were clear enough; my set theory is rusty, is all.

Comment: @JonathanY., more importantly, your comment about the order on $\mathbb{Z}'$ extending to an ordering of $\mathbb{Q}'$ is interesting. I'm going to edit the question in line with that comment. Is there a link you can supply that spells out the details a little?

Comment: Not that I have at my disposal, but suppose an integral domain is totally ordered and the order plays nice with the operations $a\leq b$ implies $a+c\leq b+c$ and $0\leq a,b$ implies $0\leq ab$), there is very little to verify in order to show that the ordering extends to the field of fractions that way.

Comment: @JonathanY., interesting. It sounds like if $\mathbb{Z}'$ is a totally ordered integral domain, then each of $\mathbb{N}',$ $\mathbb{M}'$ and $\mathbb{Q}'$ can be defined in a natural way. If so, then the $\mathbb{Z}'$ defined in the question is just one example of this phenomenon.

Comment: Indeed. I find it best to deal with the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}^\prime$, its (ordered) field of quotients $\mathbb{Q}^\prime$, and the positive cone of that field $\mathbb{M}^\prime$. The rest can be considered as subsets of these well researched structures.

Comment: @JonathanY., yeah makes sense. But why ignore $\mathbb{N}'$? It seems to have fairly nice properties. By the way, do you know if there's a way to recover $\mathbb{Z}'$ from $\mathbb{Q}'$? If so, each of the four structures uniquely determine the other three.

Comment: @JonathanY., wouldn't that cyclic group be isomorphic to the usual integers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10230/discussion-between-jonathan-y-and-user18921)

Comment: @JonathanY., hey I'm not really sure how to fix my definition of the order on $\mathbb{Q}',$ so please feel free to edit the question if you know the details.

Comment: Well $\mathbb{Q}^\prime$ is the same field usually denoted $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. Should I refer to the known structures by their name, or does that nullify the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in the surreal numbers, a totally ordered Field (capitalized because it is a proper class) in which the ordinal numbers with the Hessenberg operations embed.  (Or just form the quotient Field of the ordinals with respect to the Hessenberg operations.  The usual construction works because both operations are cancellative.)